# Mvc4 model base om JSON

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am writing an `mVC4` application and i would like to create a model to generate the following JSON file:

```
{
"area": {
       "areaid": "1",
       "venueid": "41",
       "fnames": "12",
          "s": [{"Id":1,"V":"0,1,2,2,1,1,1,0B-001,0,0,0,"},
                {"Id":2,"V":"2,1,2,2,1,1,1,0B-001,0,0,0,"},
                {"Id":3,"V":"3,1,2,2,1,1,1,0B-001,0,0,0,"}]
         }
 }
```

Something like that?

```
public class Area
{
    [Key]
    public int areaid { get; set; }
    public int venueid { get; set; }
    public int fnames { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public List<Book> s { get; set; }

} 

public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string V { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that should work. Here's the result from using Visual Studio 2013's Paste JSON as Classes feature...

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Area area { get; set; }
}

public class Area
{
    public string areaid { get; set; }
    public string venueid { get; set; }
    public string fnames { get; set; }
    public List<Book> s { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string V { get; set; }
}
```